# Pages are hashed as of today

Tags: pages

Beginning 1/24/2017, some pages of my site (psychological.com) will recurrently appear as hash (see below). A refresh may remove this but it will recur.  It is not solely on blog entries. It is also on static pages. The only change I can recall is having updated a plugin "Add To Any" button although the day before I updated "All in One Security"  Any help and/or recommendations appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you defined the page encoding in your website's header?

Comment: Also if possible,please paste the code that is generating your  static page. There is probably a character that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Try cleaning up your site using a security plugin such as Sucuri. May be your site is compromised! https://sucuri.net

Comment: I was using W3 Cache plug in. I have now disabled that.   It "seems" to have stopped the hashed pages.  A page of hash would appear but if re-loaded, the page would be fine suggesting that something was being held in the cache.  I think a plug in like W3 has been helpful, but if it no longer works...or if there is no alternative...